# How to support Desktop Website for Tablets?

Tags: javascript, extjs, responsive-design, tablet, extjs6

We have `ExtJS running application` for desktop browser precisely..Last month we have `upgraded to ExtJS 6` successfully..But right now we are facing some of `challenges in tablet support`..We are expecting same website will work for Tablet also..

I'm facing so many issue at a time while supporting a desktop website for Tablet and may be for Mobile(in Future).

So, I want to ask question about some general issues,

1) what I want to do while supporting same website application for Tablet screen ?

2) How do I deal with small text button on Tablet screen ?

3) How do I use responsive config from ExtJS 6 to support Tablet Screen ?

4) What are the most general To Do's we do while switching desktop website to Tablet ?

Comment: I am glad at least you find it as Question ...I believe it as programming question..Thanks

Comment: Check out twitter bootstrap for responsive design.

Comment: See: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/application_architecture/developing_for_multiple_screens_and_environments.html

Answer (score 0):

Media queries will be your best friend to do that

Comment: @kendy..hey yes media query...but I can not add media query css for each existing css...

Comment: I don't know another way to do that.

Comment: Searching for `viewport meata tag` -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Answer (score 0):

Removed view port meta tag from head...Working fine in Landscape and Portrait mode for Tablets and for desktop also..Cheers..[Stop using the viewport meta tag](http://blog.javierusobiaga.com/stop-using-the-viewport-tag-until-you-know-ho)